# How to retrive data from api when there are serveral arrays inside JSON with React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json

[image]I am trying to retrieve data with map() method from this api. https://api.nasa.gov/DONKI/CME?startDate=yyyy-MM-dd&endDate=yyyy-MM-dd&api_key=DEMO_KEY

I am able to retrieve data from the first array but there's antoher array inside the main array where I get the react error when trying to retrieve with another loop. The data needs to be retreived have been hilighted in the image...

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


const AstronomyPic = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/DONKI/CME?startDate=yyyy-MM-dd&endDate=yyyy-MM-dd&api_key=DEMO_KEY')
          .then(response => setImages (response.data)).
    catch(error =>console.error(" Error fetchin users", error)); 
      }, []);
  return (
    <div>

        <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Astronomy</h1>
        <ol>
        {images.map((image) => (
        <div><li>
          <p>{image.activityID}</p>
          <p>{image.catalog}</p>
          <p>{image.startTime}</p>
          <p>{image.sourceLocation}</p>
          <p>{image.activeRegionNum}</p>
          <p>{image.link}</p>
          <p>{image.note}</p>
          <p>Items: {images.items.map((item) => (
            <p>{item.instruments}</p>
          ))}</p>
          </li>
         
        </div>
         
      ))}
      </ol>
      

</div>

)

}

export default AstronomyPic
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QQ3E.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QQ3E.jpg)

Comment: Can you post response data JSON without the image?

Comment: JSON response data is too long to post. This is the link that leads to data  https://api.nasa.gov/DONKI/CME?startDate=yyyy-MM-dd&endDate=yyyy-MM-dd&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be instruments are not available in all elements. You can avoid any null reference exception using the optional chaining operator. Refer the code below :

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';


const AstronomyPic = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/DONKI/CME?startDate=yyyy-MM-dd&endDate=yyyy-MM-dd&api_key=DEMO_KEY')
          .then(response => setImages (response.data)).
    catch(error =>console.error(" Error fetchin users", error)); 
      }, []);
  return (
    <div>

        <h1 className="text-center mt-5">Astronomy</h1>
        <ol>
        {images?.map((image) => (
        <div><li>
          <p>{image.activityID}</p>
          <p>{image.catalog}</p>
          <p>{image.startTime}</p>
          <p>{image.sourceLocation}</p>
          <p>{image.activeRegionNum}</p>
          <p>{image.link}</p>
          <p>{image.note}</p>
          <p>Items: {image?.items?.map((item) => (
            <p>{item?.instruments}</p> // Use Optional chaining after item
          ))}</p>
          </li>
         
        </div>
         
      ))}
      </ol>
      

</div>

)

}

export default AstronomyPic
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some item does not have an `instruments` attribute. You might want to check before you loop through the `instruments` attribute.

```
const AstronomyPic = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
    {
      images.map((image) => (
        <>
          <p>...some other attributes</p>
          { image.instruments && <>
            instruments attribute is defined, loop through instruments here
          </>}
          <p>...some other attributes</p>
        </>
      )
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```